# How to get list of active regions per country through flexible search

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

Is there a way to get list of active regions per country, through flexible search query? When i use I18 facade,to get regions, i get both active and inactive regions.

Comment: @sandeed have a look at my edit, I have added the full FSQ to get the list of active regions per country

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like?

```
SELECT * FROM {Region} WHERE {active}=1
```

Answer (score 0):

First why do you need to get such a list ? Is using the list of countries linked to your store not filling your requirements ? Don't forget that Hybris is multi store so instead of activating or deactivating countries and regions you should attach countries to your store and use that list.

The active attribute comes from C2L item you can use the 'C2LManager' to get a list of active countries but it uses the Jalo Layer, here is an example using Groovy :

```
import java.util.Set
import de.hybris.platform.jalo.c2l.Country
import de.hybris.platform.jalo.c2l.Region
import de.hybris.platform.jalo.c2l.C2LManager
import java.util.Iterator

Set<Country> countries = C2LManager.getInstance().getActiveCountries()

Iterator it = countries.iterator()

Country country = it.next()
println country.getIsoCode()

Set<Region> regions = country.getRegions()
println regions.size()
```

---

EDIT : the FSQ to get all active regions names :

```
SELECT {re:name} 
    FROM {Region as re JOIN Country as co on {re:country} = {co:pk}}
    WHERE {re:active}=1 and {co:active}=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexible Search Query

`select {region.pk} from {Country as country}, {Region as region} where {region.country} = {country.pk} and {region.active} = 1 and {country.isocode} = 'US'`